# WPF templating difference between triggers and visualStateManager

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, visualstatemanager

I would like to know what difference is between triggers and visualStateManager. I am templating ComboBox and on the official MSDN sites (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx) they are using VisualStateManager for changing colors of selected comboboxitem. But the same you can do with triggers. 
Is there some differences between?? For example VisualStateManager will be "quicklier" or i dont know. And i would like to know what is better to use.

I am noob in templating and i dont understand it too much, so what i can use right now is triggers (that i understand), but VisualStateManager and some storyboards are big unknow for me right now.

Comment: Originally VisualStateManager was included in Silverlight, then it was added into WPF at a later time. Here is a good explanation of the different philosophies: http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2008/06/why-the-silverl.html  and here ... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers.aspx . For a "noob"...VSM and States are probably easier to follow and design with in Expression Blend.

Comment: And the functionality is a same?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that our programming world tries to separate concerns between people, we can conclude that VisualStateManager is really useful tool to make a clear separation of responsibilities.

There is a distinct separation of responsibilities:  the control author specifies what the visual states of a control are and determines when a control goes into each visual state;  the template author specifies what the control looks like in each visual state.

[see this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers.aspx)